# ValueError: time data 1.2.20 does not match format %m/%d/%y

Tags: python, date, format

Why do i keep getting this error?

What i want: input with eu-dates, creating a range of the dates and creating a variable with the value 'month and year of first date'. Since the code reads the dates in us format i have to change the format. I need the list to work with and the variable to name an output.
but the code reads the input as us-date and makes a wrong range.
so i tried so change the format but i keep getting a Value error.

if want to give the input 1.2.20 and 10.2.20
and i want the output to be: Feb_20

```
start_date = input("Enter Start Date: ")
end_date = input("Enter Last (including) Date: ")

start_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
end_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%d/%m/%y')

date_list=[]
for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)+1):
    date_list.append((start_date + datetime.timedelta(n)).strftime("%d %m %y"))

file_version = (start_date).strftime("%b") + "_" +(start_date).strftime("%y")

print(file_version)
```

but thats what i get:

```
ValueError: time data '1.2.20' does not match format '%m/%d/%y'
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What don't you understand? Your format string has `/`, but your dates have `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input to be `1.20.20` for Feb 20, 2020, use

```
strptime(start_date, '%d.%m.%y')
```

You need to change the delimiter from `/` to `.`, and put `%d` first.

Comment: What did you think it was for?

Comment: i just didnt pay any attention to it =S